# How to move labels from one tab to another in notebook tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm starting to get to know Tkinter but i'm stuck at a point as i'm experimenting and practicing; i couldn't figure out how to move tkinter elements such as Frame or Labels from one tab to another in Tkinter Notebook. 
A resourceful link or an answer concerning my problem would be very helpful!

P.S: It's my first time asking a question so apologies if i did something wrong.

Comment: Users in here will *help* you, but will not write the whole thing for you.  Add your code and what is wrong with it, we can help after.  See [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Use the `in_` argument to simply pack them in the new Frame. ie `label_instance.pack(in_=new_frame`. If you want to remove them from the old frame too, call `label_instance.pack_forget()` first. Similar if you are using `grid` or `place`.

Comment: @Novel: you don't have to call `pack_forget()`. A widget can only be in one place at a time, so when it's added to a new place it's automatically removed from the old.

Comment: Thank you @Nic3500, i will add my code from now onwards!

Comment: Works fine now! thanks @Novel

Comment: Got it! @BryanOakley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly unusual to move widgets around between frames. Usually it's easiest just to delete the old widget and create a new one in the new location. However, it is possible to move widgets, though with some constraints.

Widgets exist in a tree-like structure, with the root window as the start of the tree. Except for the root window, all other widgets have a parent. You cannot move a widget to a different branch of the tree, so to move from one frame to another, both frames plus the label need to have the same parent.

Normally a widget will be placed in it's parent when using `pack`, `place`, or `grid`. You can change that by using the `in_` parameter.

The following example illustrates the technique. Notice that the label to be moved (`the_label`) is a child of the notebook rather than a child of one of the tabs, and we use the `in_` parameter to designate which frame should have the label.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def moveToOne():
    the_label.pack(in_=tab1, expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

def moveToTwo():
    the_label.pack(in_=tab2, expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

root = tk.Tk()

notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
toolbar = ttk.Frame(root)

toolbar.pack(side="top", fill="x")
notebook.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
notebook.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
notebook.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")

the_label = tk.Label(notebook, text="Click a button to move me")

b1 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Move to tab 1", command=moveToOne)
b2 = tk.Button(toolbar, text="Move to tab 2", command=moveToTwo)
b1.pack(side="left")
b2.pack(side="left")

# initialize it to be on the first tab
moveToOne()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! Code really explained what i was trying to understand. :)